# How to install go-sql-driver on Windows

Tags: windows, git, go

I am trying to install  [go-sql-driver](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/#installation) on Windows Vista but I am having problems with `GOPATH`.

I installed git as suggested and added `GOPATH` as a new user environment in Windows with path `C:/users/A/desktop/go`.

I ran  `go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql` in the command line but it gives me this error:

```
C:\>go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
go: missing Git command. See http://golang.org/s/gogetcmd
package github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql: exec: "git": executable file not found in %PATH%
```

When I go look at http://golang.org/s/gogetcmd it merely says download git. But it is already downloaded in my machine.

I also went ahead and created a new environement variable for `PATH` and set its path to the directory where git was installed but that did not help either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you able to execute `git` on the command line?

Comment: Can you run "git" from the command line? What does it say? If git itself doesn't exist on your `PATH`, then `go get` won't be able to invoke it.

Comment: I use git with MINGW32 that came with it. I don't know how to use git with command line.

Comment: There was an option in the installation about using windows command line but I did not choose that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download the Windows version of Git from `http://git-scm.com/downloads`.

Run the downloaded executable file, currently `Git-1.8.3-preview20130601.exe`, which will start a Git Setup wizard to install Git.

Check Git Setup Options

- Run Git from the Windows Command Prompt
- Checkout as-is, commit Unix-style line endings

Check the installation by running:

```
C:\>git --version
git version 1.8.3.msysgit.0
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. I rerun the install this time checking "Run Git from the Windows Command Prompt" now I see that it set the PATH. To test if the driver was installed I run a small program that imported the driver and it compiled fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Git is in the `%PATH%` environment variable and ensure Git is installed. If you cannot run `git --version` in the command prompt, then the Git binary directory isn't listed in your `%PATH%`. Fix this by adding Git to the path, close the command prompt, and run git `--version` in a new command prompt. If you're still having issues, then you might be having other problems.

Answer (score 0):

Install the **GIT BASH** desktop app in your Windows PC. The download link is [here](https://gitforwindows.org/). Once installed, open the shell and type:

```
go get -u github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
```

This will install driver for Golang's MySQL database package